# How do you install Boost on MacOS?

Tags: c++, macos, boost

How do you install Boost on MacOS?
Right now I can't find bjam for the Mac.

Comment: You can always try like "port search <whatever>" - in your case boost - when unsure.

Comment: I've used both macports and brew. I use them together when necessary (`sudo port -t install X`) but I prefer brew over macports in most cases.

Comment: For newer M1 : `arch -arm64 brew install boost` works

Answer (score 164, accepted):

Download [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/), and run the following command:

```
sudo port install boost
```

Comment: if you prefer running things through root

`sudo -s /opt/local/bin/port install boost`

Comment: I don't believe macports is dead inasmuch as it has fallen out of fashion.

Comment: What about doing `brew install boost boost-python`?

Comment: How is this accepted over the Homebrew answer? That makes no sense to me...

Comment: Because the asker presumably uses, or at least used to use, MacPorts.

Comment: I don't think its wise to use both home-brew and Mac ports -- so it is convenient so that there is an answer for both.

Comment: I don't think it's wise to use Macports :)

Answer (score 339):

You can get the latest version of Boost by using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/).

`brew install boost`.

Comment: How long does it take different people? Took me 48 mins with 2 GB RAM, not sure what CPU.

Comment: @LukeStanley AFAIK Homebrew uses pre-compiled packages ("bottles") for Boost these days, making the installation a matter of seconds.

Comment: Matter of seconds? I'm on Mountain Lion, 2.9GHz processor, 8GB of RAM and installation is still not complete after 15min.

Comment: I'm using a late 2013 MBP with i7 8gb ram. The fan was running fast when the compilation was going on. It finished just before "it's too long".

Comment: Would be cautious of the version of boost library getting picked up by brew though. I think by default when i last installed using brew was 1.6. That didnt work for me as the others had dependency with 1.57. So, i forced brew to pick that version while installing

Comment: I can't find a boost.framework file anywhere after doing a brew install, anyone know where to look?

Comment: Took about a minute

Comment: 20 minutes here, 4 GB RAM.

Comment: less than 1 minute with 16GB RAM 3GHz processor, OSX 10.11.6

Comment: Hi, nice answer! What if I want to install boost@1.58? There is no 1.58 available with homebrew?

Comment: This doesn't install Boost.log.

Comment: As for 2021-10-23, it installs 1.76.0 (Boost.log is included); total time <1 min

Comment: @LukeStanley Less than a minute for me. M1 Macbook Pro though.

Comment: or `boost-python3` so cmake could detect it

Answer (score 122):

Just get the source, and compile Boost yourself; it has become very easy. Here is an example for the current version of Boost on the current macOS as of this writing:

1. Download the the .tar.gz from https://www.boost.org/users/download/#live
2. Unpack and go into the directory:

   ```
   tar -xzf boost_1_50_0.tar.gz
   cd boost_1_50_0
   ```
3. Configure (and build `bjam`):

   ```
   ./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/some/dir/you/would/like/to/prefix
   ```
4. Build:

   ```
   ./b2
   ```
5. Install:

   ```
   ./b2 install
   ```

Depending on the prefix you choose in Step 3, you might need to sudo Step 5, if the script tries copy files to a protected location.

Comment: Best route if you need to link against boost_thread.  The standard brew recipes don't seem to include it.

Comment: If you want to install other executables that depends on boost at default runtime environment ok, use other answers, in any other case, use this answer. Best for you to know when you ara compiling with boost and how. You will have it as as it is supposed to be. And Most important, It will force you to think where boost will be on Continuous Integration (Build) server, and if has an deployment server too.

Comment: Can  you please explain step 3? @snies

Comment: @MAS (I did not try it today. But the bootstrap.sh should come with the tar.gz file. It configures the build process and creates the bjam build tool. The "prefix" is a common option for build tools which will be prefixed to the install path. This means, that if a file would be installed in /bin it will instead be installed in /prefix/bin when the install command is issued. You can use that to avoid permission problems. For example i install optional packages i use for development in /home/snies/opt/bin instead of /bin so i don't need root permissions and don't mess up my system.

Answer (score 7):

Install both of them using homebrew separately.

> brew install boost 
>   brew install bjam

Answer (score 6):

Unless your compiler is different than the one supplied with the Mac XCode Dev tools, just follow the instructions in section 5.1 of [Getting Started Guide for Unix Variants](http://www.boost.org/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html). The configuration and building of the latest source couldn't be easier, and it took all about about 1 minute to configure and 10 minutes to compile.

Answer (score 5):

[Fink](http://www.finkproject.org/) appears to have a full set of Boost packages...

With fink installed and running just do

```
fink install boost1.35.nopython
```

at the terminal and accept the dependencies it insists on. Or use

```
fink list boost
```

to get a list of different packages that are availible.

Answer (score 5):

Install Xcode from the mac app store.
Then use the command:

```
  /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

the above will install homebrew and allow you to use brew in terminal

then just use command :

```
brew install boost
```

which would then install the boost libraries to `<your macusername>/usr/local/Cellar/boost`

Answer (score 4):

In order to avoid troubles compiling third party libraries that need boost installed in your system, run this:

```
sudo port install boost +universal
```

Answer (score 4):

## Try `+universal`

One thing to note: in order for that to make a difference you need to have built `python` with `+universal`, if you haven't or you're not sure you can just rebuild `python +universal`. This applies to both **brew** as well as **macports**.

```
$ brew reinstall python
$ brew install boost
```

OR

```
$ sudo port -f uninstall python
$ sudo port install python +universal
$ sudo port install boost +universal
```

Comment: For brew there is no +universal stated?

Comment: But port seems promising...
And actually they decided that it's not worth the effort or they cannot maintain it: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/10307 what a blow to brew

Comment: Ah but actually ports also does not support boost-build universal :(

Answer (score 3):

you can download bjam for OSX (or any other OS) [here](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=7586&package_id=72941)

Comment: No hint what is bjam and why you think your answer fixes boost related issue.

Comment: @TõnuSamuel - OP mentions bjam in the original post.

Answer (score 2):

If you are too lazy like me:
`conda install -c conda-forge boost`