# How to add any C++ library to Mac OS X

Tags: c++, macos

I want to add several C++ libraries, such as Boost, to work in Mac. How can I do that?

Comment: There is a boost specific question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104322/how-do-you-install-boost-on-macos

Comment: This is why I switched to Linux.

Answer (score 1):

If you have homebrew installed boost can easily be installed from the command line:

```
brew install boost
```

Depending on what the other libraries you want to install are you can do the same with those. Just make sure it's a "Formula" [check here](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/tree/master/Library/Formula). If it's not a "Formula" then read the documentation for the library about installation on osx.