# Trouble installing Boost C++

Tags: c++, macos, boost, installation

Right now, I am trying to install boost on my computer, a Mac running Mavericks. I have downloaded and decompressed boost into the directory

```
$HOME/local/src/
```

After decompressing, I moved it to a new directory inside the boost source directory:

```
tools/build/v2
```

I then executed

```
./boostrap.sh --with-toolset=gcc
```

This all went fine. The next step is where the problems start: in the src file, I executed the following command:

```
tools/build/v2/boost_1_57_0/b2 install --prefix=PREFIX --toolset=gcc --with-program_options --with-filesystem
```

It then returned the following error:

```
Unable to load Boost.Build: could not find "boost-build.jam"

---------------------------------------------------------------
BOOST_ROOT must be set, either in the environment, or 
on the command-line with -sBOOST_ROOT=..., to the root
of the boost installation.
```

It says it can't find boost-build.jam, but I open up the folder in Finder and I see boost-build.jam right there in my boost_1_57_0 folder. What can I do to execute this command? Am I doing something wrong? If it runs correctly, I should have a PREFIX/include directory with header files for boost. What can I do to get this? Here is a link to the site for Boost if that will help:

http://www.boost.org

Also, I have already found this page on how to install Boost:

[How do you install Boost on MacOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104322/how-do-you-install-boost-on-macos)

Will the method this user describes give the same result that the code above would if it was functioning properly? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install brew:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Then do:

```
brew install boost-build
```

After that you will have the `bjam` executable in `/usr/local/bin/bjam`.

Comment: in what folder should I install boost-build--src, v2, or boost_1_57_0?

Comment: brew will place it under `/usr/local/Cellar/boost-build/`

Comment: Okay--I did that with brew, but I am still a little confused . Was the boost-build with brew supposed to replace my non-functioning code I wrote above, or was it supposed to make the code I wrote above work? I ran     tools/build/v2/boost_1_57_0/b2 install --prefix=PREFIX --toolset=gcc --with-program_options --with-filesystem again, and it gives me the same error (sorry--I'm new to Mac. My last two computers were Dells).

Comment: The brew installation is supposed to replace your code, you don't need to manually download or compile from source, brew does it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to elyase for his response. I have also found a way to solve the problem posted above that doesn't use brew. I was making the mistake of making a new tools/build/v2 folder in my src folder--however, I was supposed to cd into the tools/build folder already in the downloaded boost folder. Also, in the newer versions of boost, there is no v2 folder--so just use

```
tools/build/b2 install --prefix=PREFIX --toolset=gcc --with-program_options --with-filesystem
```

Hopefully this will help people who are new to Mac (like me) who are having similar problems.