# "Symbol not found" when trying to import a Python module that uses Boost on OS/X

Tags: python, c++, macos, boost, boost-python

Based on [How do you install Boost on MacOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104322/how-do-you-install-boost-on-macos) I just installed Homebrew on my Mac and then installed boost and boost-python with

```
brew install boost
brew install boost-python
```

Then I installed pyhash with

```
pip install pyhash
```

It seemed to work, though it did say, `warning: no files found matching '*.cc' under directory 'src'` a couple times. But when I run `import pyhash` from Python I get this:

```
import pyhash
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-2-c4d444636750>", line 1, in <module>
    import pyhash

  File "/Users/kuzzooroo/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyhash.py", line 7, in <module>
    import _pyhash

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/kuzzooroo/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pyhash.so, 2): Symbol not found: __ZN5boost6python7objects15function_objectERKNS1_11py_functionERKSt4pairIPKNS0_6detail7keywordES9_E
  Referenced from: /Users/kuzzooroo/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pyhash.so
  Expected in: dynamic lookup
```

Uninstalling and reinstalling pyhash doesn't help.

I'm using OS/X Yosemite. Here's my Python version info: `Python 2.7.9 |Anaconda 1.8.0 (x86_64)| (default, Dec 15 2014, 10:37:34) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.`

Comment: I'm having this problem too. Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @kilojoules, I'm afraid not.

Comment: I started a bounty for a similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29777337/macosx-boost-python-pyftgl-symbol-not-found-expected-in-flat-namespace