# About an error of "boost not found"

Tags: python, c++, boost

I have installed boost through Homebrew as stated in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104322/how-do-you-install-boost-on-macos) but after I enter "brew install boost"
it showed

```
Warning: boost-1.60.0_1 already installed, it's just not linked
```

And the purpose of installing boost is it is a dependency of installing a package called "astra-toolbox", then after installing boost, I proceed as stated in this page: [here2](https://github.com/astra-toolbox/astra-toolbox)

and I typed

```
cd build/linux
./autogen.sh   
./configure --with-python --prefix=/usr/local/astra
```

as stated in the page but it shows the error:

```
configure: error: boost not found
```

So I cannot proceed to install this package.

So what should I do in order to have astra-toolbox installed? Or how to install boost correctly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Who do Homebrew support say?

Comment: I installed boost to /usr/local/boost_1_60_0 and made a symlink to /usr/include/boost with; ln -s /usr/local/boost_1_60_0/boost /usr/include/boost. Also I set BOOST_ROOT=/usr/local/boost_1_60_0/boost . My install got through boost at least. Still haven't tried the astra toolbox yet, so this is not an answer at this time. Hope it helps!