# OS X, CMake, Boost: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "boost::system::detail::generic_category_instance"

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I'm trying to compile [this Git repo](https://github.com/fixxxedpoint/quorum_intersection) using the given instructions. However, on the `cmake --build .;` line, I run into the following issue.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::system::detail::generic_category_instance", referenced from:
      boost::system::generic_category() in quorum_intersection.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I edited the `CMakeLists.txt` file to incorporate some of the previous answers I saw on similar StackOverflow threads. Below is the CMakeLists.txt file I'm using right now.

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (stellar-quorums-verifier)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED OFF)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)
find_package(Boost 1.66.0 COMPONENTS graph log program_options REQUIRED system)

if(Boost_FOUND)
    add_definitions(-DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK)
    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    add_executable(quorum_intersection quorum_intersection.cpp)
    target_link_libraries(quorum_intersection ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
    TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(quorum_intersection ${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY} ${Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY})
endif()

set(CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT "-lpthread")
set(CMAKE_HAVE_THREADS_LIBRARY 1)
set(CMAKE_USE_WIN32_THREADS_INIT 0)
set(CMAKE_USE_PTHREADS_INIT 1)
set (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_WORKS TRUE)
set (CMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS TRUE)
```

I installed Boost by downloading the source and running `./b2 cxxstd=14` and `./b2 install`, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104322/how-do-you-install-boost-on-macos).

What confuses me is that the output of `cmake ../;` includes

```
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Boost version: 1.68.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   graph
--   log
--   program_options
--   system
--   date_time
--   log_setup
--   filesystem
--   thread
--   regex
--   chrono
--   atomic
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/Uthsav/Desktop/quorum_intersection-master/build
```

so it seems like system should be defined? So I'm not sure why it says boost::system is undefined. I've spent almost the whole night trying to run the code from this Git repo -- if anyone has any advice, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I'd consider filing a bug report. For a question here, you'd first have to extract a [mcve] from the code.

Answer (score 2):

I got the build working by adding

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++14 -O3 -lboost_system -lboost_thread")
```

to the CMakeLists.txxt file. Not sure why this works, but I found it online somewhere.