# How to fix 'boost/operators.hpp' file not found' error in react-native

Tags: react-native, boost

when I use 'react-native run-ios', there is some error, 'boost/operators.hpp' file not found.
I can not build and run my project:

react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.59.9
npm: 6.9.0
yarn: 1.16.0
node: v12.4.0
os: macos 10.14.5
xcode: 10.2.1

```
▸ Compiling JSIDynamic.cpp

❌  /Users/lidongbo/WorkBentch/ReactNative/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/React/../third-party/folly-2018.10.22.00/folly/dynamic.h:63:10: 'boost/operators.hpp' file not found

#include <boost/operators.hpp>
              ^


▸ Analyzing JSCRuntime.cpp
▸ Analyzing jsi.cpp
error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening AwesomeProject.xcodeproj
```

project can build and run.

Comment: looks like a dependency might need boost, try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104322/how-do-you-install-boost-on-macos

Comment: @jman  I resolve the problem.
boost_1_63_0.tar.gz
double-conversion-1.1.6.tar.gz
folly-2018.10.22.00.tar.gz
glog-0.3.5.tar.gz

These files are not completely downloaded due to network reasons.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This might due to incomplete pods install - try deleting `ios/Pods` folder and run `pod install` under `ios`.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me. I'm using RN 0.61.

Comment: Deleting and re-instaling pods helped (RN 0.63.1)

Comment: That didn't help for me, I tried to delete both ios/Pods and the Podfile.lock, but no luck.

Answer (score 31):

If you get this issue in react-native-reanimated after upgrading to react-native 0.66 update your react-native-reanimated in `package.json`

```
Try "react-native-reanimated": "2.3.0-beta.2"
```

Don't forget to run `yarn install` or `npm install` to update your packages. Also do a `pod install` for `ios` and restart your server instance .

EDIT:

Support for `react-native@0.66` has been officially added by `react-native-reanimated@2.2.3` It is less buggy and a lot more issues have been solved.

Also check [issue on github.](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/2456)

Comment: This one solved my problem.

Comment: I am glad it worked for you @FelipeValencia

Comment: Be aware RN 0.66 doesn't work very well with reanimated 2.3.0-beta.2 .Noticed some ios bugs with app freezing but hopefully that is fixed by the time you reading this.  https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/32329

Comment: where exactly should this be added? @HillkimHenry

Comment: @TJD'Alessandro In package.json where your react-native-reanimated is defined. Don't forget to run  `yarn install` or `npm install` to update your packages. Also do a `pod install` for `ios` and restart your server instance .

Answer (score 4):

An alternative error for the same issue that I encountered was:

```
ios/Pods/boost-for-react-native/boost/operators.hpp:97:10: 'boost/config.hpp' file not found
```

To fix it, you need to clear cocoa pods and cache and re-install.

1. Delete cocoa pods cache: `rm -r ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods`
2. Delete the `Pods` folder and the `Podfile.lock` usually located in `<project_root>/ios`.
3. Reinstall pods: `pod update`

Comment: `pod update` would not fix the issue for me, but following this steps fixed the error

Answer (score 1):

You must delete cache from wherever ios concerns; Here's the process I do to clear its cache:

1. Delete npm cache: `npm cache clean --force`
2. Delete All ios temp files: `cd ios && rm -r Pods/ Podfile.lock {yourProject}.xcworkspace`
3. Clear Cocoapods Cache: `rm -r ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods`
4. now install pods via npx: `cd .. && npx pod-install`

Answer (score 1):

So I was also getting the error `boost/operators.hpp file not found` but my issue was from using `:path` instead of `:podspec` in my `Podfile`. I'm working on an [integrated RN app inside of a Native iOS app](https://reactnative.dev/docs/integration-with-existing-apps), so I was manually adding the pods to the `Podfile` (something I will not do from now on).

`pod 'boost', :path => ...`

instead of

`pod 'boost', :podspec => ...`

It might not be the most common fix but hoping it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve the problem.

```
boost_1_63_0.tar.gz
double-conversion-1.1.6.tar.gz
folly-2018.10.22.00.tar.gz
glog-0.3.5.tar.gz
```

These files are not completely downloaded due to network reasons.
The file url is :
`{your proejct}/node_modules/react-native/scripts/ios-install-third-party.sh` at lowest line.

Comment: .sh file contain the file`s  dowload url.

Comment: I don't think it's network issue though. My internet is solid and retried several times, seeing the same isseu.

Comment: I retried cleaning and building multiple times. I also tried to blow out pod files and Podfile.lock and installing, and still no luck. This is not a network issue. {your proejct}/node_modules/react-native/scripts/ios-install-third-party.sh file also doesn't exist for me on RN 0.66.4

Answer (score 0):

When I upgraded RN 0.64 -> 0.66, the following helped me:

1. Delete cocoa pods cache: rm -r ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods
2. Delete the Pods folder and the Podfile.lock usually located in <project_root>/ios
3. Delete Pod folder in <project_root>/ios
4. yarn add react-native-reanimated@2.2.3
5. pod install

Answer (score 0):

I literally copy pased `boost` folder to `Pods` from another MacBook which did not have this issue. Then did `pod install` again and my app started working successfully. Even if I delete the whole `Pods` folder and do `pod install` again, now `boost` pod has correct content.

I did not have to update/delete any libraries or change anything in any config files.

My issue was that `boost` folder in `Pods` was practically empty so check if there is any content inside of it first. I guess it was some caching thing that was not working properly.