# Building ReactNative 0.59.10 on XCode 12.5 ignoring Pod

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I am trying to compile and build the ReactNative project for IOS. I am now using XCode version 12.5 which is the latest at the moment. My ReactNative version is 0.59.10. Before I was compiling and building my project on XCode version 11.x and it was working fine. Then I installed the latest XCode version, 12.5. Then I deleted the node_modules folder and run the "npm install" again. When I opened the IOS project in the XCode and tried to build it, it is giving me the following error.

```
node_modules/react-native/React/../third-party/folly-2018.10.22.00/folly/dynamic.h:63:10: fatal error: 'boost/operators.hpp' file not found
#include <boost/operators.hpp>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

When I built the project in the older version of XCode, it works fine. I looked up the solution online and it seems that that is because maybe the project is not using Podfile or Pods. In ReactNative version 0.59.10, it is not using Podfile or Pods to manage the dependencies. How can I build the project? Is upgrading the ReactNative only option? Is there any other solution?

Comment: Try this answer, might be helpful.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67319700/9511497

Comment: There is not Podfile as I am using react native version 0.59.10.