# Trouble setting up Boost library with GCC-6 in Clion

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, clang, clion

I am not able to build a simple Hello World program in GCC-6 but it works fine with Clang in Clion.

[image]

Now I try to build and run the first example of Boost Date Time here

[Boost Date time Example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/date_time/examples.html)

My CMake looks like

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(Boost_Run_2)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS date_time)

add_executable(Boost_Run_2 main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(Boost_Run_2 PRIVATE Boost::date_time)
```

But it throws linker error as

```
====================[ Build | Boost_Run_2 | Debug ]=============================
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake --build /Users/alihasan/Documents/GSOC/Boost_Run_2/cmake-build-debug --target Boost_Run_2 -- -j 4
Scanning dependencies of target Boost_Run_2
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Boost_Run_2.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable Boost_Run_2
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::gregorian::greg_month::get_month_map_ptr[abi:cxx11]()", referenced from:
      unsigned short boost::date_time::month_str_to_ushort<boost::gregorian::greg_month>(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [Boost_Run_2] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Boost_Run_2.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Boost_Run_2.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [Boost_Run_2] Error 2
```

When I run the same program with Clang I am able to run it. No linker errors. So I am assuming my Boost Libraries are set up properly.

I want to be able to run the same program using GCC-6/G++-6.

I have a macOS Mojave 10.14.3 and I used `brew install boost` to install Boost libraries.

Comment: The C++ compiler is called `g++-6`, not `gcc-6`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat thanks a lot. It was silly. It worked. I'll update my question. Now I don't have to specify a linker to build C++ Standard Files. But still, Boost code is giving error. I don't think I have problem setting up the Boost library as it works fine with Clang.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue.

I realized my Boost libraries were not installed properly.

For some reason, Homebrew does not install Boost libraries properly and you've got to install it the way it's mentioned in their documentation.

[Getting Started on Unix Variants](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html)

[StackOverflow question How do you install Boost on MacOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/users/262822/snies)

Thanks to [snies](https://stackoverflow.com/users/262822/snies) answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11297605/8093027.