# Boost multi_index not found on MacOS

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I was running `cmake .` and a line of output read `-- Could NOT find Boost: missing: multi_index (found /usr/local/lib/cmake/Boost-1.76.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found version "1.76.0"))`. It seems to me that Boost is installed but multi_index is not being found. Some things I have tried: homebrew installation, and directly installing following this thread [How do you install Boost on MacOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104322/how-do-you-install-boost-on-macos). Any suggestions as to how I can get the multi_index library installed?

Comment: `multi_index` is header only so there is no library to find

Comment: @AlanBirtles I am a little new to C++ so what does that mean

Comment: difficult to tell without a [mre] but I'd guess you're trying to link to `multi_index` but there's nothing to link to so it doesn't work

Comment: in cmake linking a target does not necessarily involve linking a library at compile time. It also enables inheriting settings, like include directories and build flags. It could be useful for header-only libraries too.